# How to echo JSON in PHP (stdClass Object)?

Tags: php, json

This is a simple JSON but it cannot access an item. 
I send the that JSON to get.php and there just print_r the JSON and in parsing JSON response is problem.

My code:

```
$url = "http://localhost/get.php";    
    $data = array(
        'item1'      => 'value1',
        'item2'      => 'value2',
        'item3'      => 'value3'
    );


$content = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status == 201 ) {
die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, false);
$result=json_encode($json_response);
$data=json_decode($result);
```

How can I echo item 1 or 2 ?

This is get.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: the json is irrelevant. once it's decoded, it's a PHP data structure, like any other PHP data structure. there will be absolutely NO trace within it that says "I used to be json". You access the data like any other php structure.

Comment: Simple `echo $result['item1'];`, `echo $result['item2'];` will do. BTW there's no point encoding it, and then decoding it again.

Comment: What does this have to do with `stdClass Object`? When you use `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()` it returns an associative array, not an object.

Comment: As Rajdeep just said, echo it based upon the name you gave the index, as you would any array. If you want to loop through, use a loop.

Comment: @Barmar i did not get answer  guys !!

Comment: @RajdeepPaul's comment should work. If it doesn't, you're doing something different from what you showed in the question. See http://ideone.com/Az18Df

Comment: @Barmar when i echo it is like this   
stdClass Object ( [item1] => value1 [item2] => value2 [item3] => value3 )

Comment: @MohammadaliMirahamed That would happen if you did `$result = json_decode($json);`, without the `true` argument.

Comment: If you do that, it should be `echo $result->item1;`.

Comment: @Barmar Tnx  i do it you told me .in last comment but the php echo this error Trying to get property of non-object 
for this echo $result->item1;

Comment: Please post your exact code that's printing `stdClass Object...`. That looks like `var_dump`, not `echo`.

Comment: @Barmar it returns this 

string 'stdClass Object
(
    [item1] => value1
    [item2] => value2
    [item3] => value3
)
' (length=86)

when Var_dum($result)

Comment: It looks like you've put the output of `print_r($object)` into a string variable. Please edit your question and show the whole code.

Comment: @Barmar edit question

Comment: We need to see what `get.php` is doing. It appears to be returning `print_r()` output, not JSON.

Comment: @Barmar i put get.php code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `get.php` uses `print_r()`, it's not returning JSON. It needs to use `json_encode()`.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then your `curl` script can decode it properly.

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, false);
echo 'Item1 = ' . $response->item1 . '<br>';
echo 'Item2 = ' . $response->item2 . '<br>';
echo 'Item3 = ' . $response->item3;
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Bro . :X :X

Answer (score 0):

You don't need set second param in json_decode function for getting stdClass.

```
$data = array(
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3'
);
$json=json_encode($data);
$result=json_decode($json);
echo $result->item1;
echo $result->item2;
echo $result->item3;
```

Or you can work with array

```
$json=json_encode($data);
$result=json_decode($json, true);
echo $result['item1'];
echo $result['item2'];
echo $result['item3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()` to encode the data , then print the json

```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
echo $result['item1']; //Echo item 1.
```

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: You can see the keys in the question, they're not numeric.

Comment: That's why i added the other answer. It looks like he doesn't get array as result though. `http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php` says `json_decode($json, true)` returns array...